# How to configure tabwidth in djhtml?

Tags: django, django-templates, indentation, tab-size

I've Djhtml installed and working correctly and I want Djhtml (https://github.com/rtts/djhtml) to configure the tabwidth from 4 (default) to 2 of the django template. But due to lack of documentation I'm unable to do. This line in readme.md of the djhtml
**-t / --tabwidth: set tabwidth (default is 4)** give a general of how to do it, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried these commands but was unable to change the tabwidth:

`djhtml -t/2 detail.html`;

`djhtml -t/tabwidth=2 detail.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is like any other command line arguments, then you need to remove the slash and use a space; you can use the following 2 options:

Using the short version `-t`:

```
djhtml -t 2 detail.html
```

or using the long version `--tabwidth` (with 2 lines infront):

```
djhtml --tabwidth 2 detail.html
```